# Can a familiar be targeted by the Awaken spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, targeting

Can a familiar obtained by the Find Familiar spell be Awakened, giving it 10 INT and a language?

Answer (score 32):

### A familiar from Find Familiar can't be awakened.

The [*awaken*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/awaken) spell needs to target a beast or plant:

> you touch a Huge or smaller beast or plant

However, the familiar from [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) is not considered a beast:

> the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.

Therefore you can't use *awaken* on a familiar from *find familiar*.